# Tab bar sliding animation in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, slide, tabbar

I have two question about this view . You can look at amazon mobile app by the way . First question is how we can add a line above to tap bar item . You can see on these pictures . Second question is also ı think that this question is more important than first one . When ı touch up new tab bar item the blue line dont change directly . It is sliding on the line where it located . How can we achieve these

[When the first Tab bar item is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E94O6.jpg) [When the second Tab bar item is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wckO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit more complicated question. You have to create a custom tabbar.
https://medium.com/nickelfox/ios-swift-custom-tabbarcontroller-with-tab-item-animation-b26f6a6e2c62

And then you can configure the animation as you like. If you want to copy the amazon one, You need a UIView(), like 2px high and animate to the right position as on the link.
This is a bit more advanced programming. But you can dig into on the shared link.